# Unknown transformer

Tags: transformer, push-pull

I have a transformer I want to find information about. I determined that there is pot core in transformer. It is a step-up transformer and it was used in push-pull topology. There are not any numbers or signs on it so I couldn't find the manufacturer.

These are the pictures of transformer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I find more information such as a datasheet? Also how can I determine the manufacturer?

Comment: (1) You can't and (2) you can't

Comment: Use an [LCR meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCR_meter) to determine the primary and secondary characteristics.

Comment: looks a lot like a 1950s-70's era VINKOR (Mullard) but unless you can find which core, that doesn't help. Measure inductances, dismantle and count turns, calculate volume and Al, and search for "ferrite pot core" matching those characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I find more information such as a datasheet?

If you have the original circuit diagram from the product's manufacturer, some technical details about the xfmr may have been given in it if you are lucky. But if you don't, you should

- dismantle the transformer, and
- count the turns of each winding taking the winding directions in the account.

Even if you dismantle the xfmr with no problems, there are a few parameters that you can't get:

- The core material *(obviously it's soft ferrite but which model from which manufacturer)*
- The isolation level, if you really care *(You can still measure it before dismantling but there's a risk of damaging the transformer)*

Simply, my answer is: **You can't.**

> Also how can I determine the manufacturer?

Some manufacturers (e.g. Würth) just put a label on the transformer. If there's none then you may still need to have the original circuit diagram from the manufacturer of the actual product. If you don't have this then you may ask the authorized technical services or repair services. Sometimes they know where to get these components.

Comment: Also note that many (most?) transformers are custom-made, even for mass-produced items.  Seldom, does a transformer label have meaning except for the one whom purchased it.  I've even been told (by a transformer manufacturer) that they would not give me the datasheet because it was a proprietary build.